# getServerSideProps in react context? (next.js pages router)

Tags: next.js, server-side-rendering, react-context

I'm using Next.js with the pages router and I'm having some issues with the global context of my application (using react createContext).

I need to have getServerSideProps and set the result of the server-side function in a global context to consume the returned values globally on my app (in this example, I use getServerSideProps to get the user's information). The problem is, getServerSideProps only works on next.js pages and not on a React Context Provider component.

How can I work around this?

Answer (score 0):

you can simply send data from `getServerSideProps` to the page component using props. then, get the data from there and pass it to a context provider. like so:

first, we have to create a context in a file:

```js
export const PostsContext = createContext([])
```

then, we pass page props to the context

```js
const Page = ({ posts }) => {
    return (
        <PostsContext.Provider value={posts}>
            ...
        </PostsContext.Provider>
    )
}

export const getServerSideProps = async () => {
    const resp = await fetch("...")

    return {
        props: {
            posts: await resp.json()
        }
    }
}

export default Page
```

and finally, we can use the data in a component:

```js
const MyComponent = () => {
    const posts = useContext(PostsContext)

    ...
}
```

feel free to ask, if it is confusing or if you have questions.